# Renaming a button after user input

Tags: objective-c, uibutton

I am a noob with Xcode and programming in general. I have a code so that a user can click on a button "Start Date" which then brings up a pop-up date picker. I want to know how to have the button "Start Date" rename itself to the date the user selects and then also allow it to be re-edited.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
- (void)changeDate:(UIDatePicker *)sender {
NSLog(@"New Date: %@", sender.date);
}

- (void)removeViews:(id)object {
[[self.view viewWithTag:9] removeFromSuperview];
[[self.view viewWithTag:10] removeFromSuperview];
[[self.view viewWithTag:11] removeFromSuperview];
}

- (void)dismissDatePicker:(id)sender {
CGRect toolbarTargetFrame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height, 320, 44);
CGRect datePickerTargetFrame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height+44, 320, 216);
[UIView beginAnimations:@"MoveOut" context:nil];
[self.view viewWithTag:9].alpha = 0;
[self.view viewWithTag:10].frame = datePickerTargetFrame;
[self.view viewWithTag:11].frame = toolbarTargetFrame;
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(removeViews:)];
[UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (IBAction)StartDate:(UIButton *)sender {
if ([self.view viewWithTag:9]) {
    return;
}
CGRect toolbarTargetFrame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height-216-44, 320, 44);
CGRect datePickerTargetFrame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height-216, 320, 216);

UIView *darkView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
darkView.alpha = 0;
darkView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
darkView.tag = 9;
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self               action:@selector(dismissDatePicker:)];
[darkView addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
[self.view addSubview:darkView];

UIDatePicker *datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,   self.view.bounds.size.height+44, 320, 216)];
datePicker.tag = 10;
datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
[datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(changeDate:)  forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[self.view addSubview:datePicker];

UIToolbar *toolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,  self.view.bounds.size.height, 320, 44)];
toolBar.tag = 11;
toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
UIBarButtonItem *spacer = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(dismissDatePicker:)];
[toolBar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:spacer, doneButton, nil]];
[self.view addSubview:toolBar];

[UIView beginAnimations:@"MoveIn" context:nil];
toolBar.frame = toolbarTargetFrame;
datePicker.frame = datePickerTargetFrame;
darkView.alpha = 0.5;
[UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

Comment: FYI - you are not renaming the button. You simply want to update its title.

Comment: You will need a global variable for the button and then update it's title with a string derived from an NSDateFormatter ...

Comment: Is your "button" a UIButton? Then look at the UIButton class documentation. Is it a UIBarButtonItem? Then look at the UIBarButtonItem (and UIBarItem) class documentation.

Comment: @CW0007007 Please no. Do not use a global for this. Use an instance variable.

Comment: Shouldn't really use an IVAR @rmaddy surely. Plus, bear in mind who's asking the question.

Comment: @CW0007007 Please explain why you think a global is better than an ivar?

Comment: By global I mean a Property i.e. in this case @property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIButton *button;